# Using .vimrc settings in bash

Tags: bash, vim

I am using `set -o vi` to use bash in vi mode. Is there a way I can use `.vimrc` settings in bash (at least the ones that makes sense) ?

Comment: how should bash know what makes sense and what not?

Comment: It would be neat if a shell used a real editor as a sort of plugin for editing the command line, but alas, this is not the case for bash. Nice idea, though.

Comment: @three i meant at least the key mappings ignoring things like foldmethod, tab etc which doesn't make any sense when you are editing a single line

Answer (score 4):

Well, `bash` and `libreadline`, which takes care of text input for `bash`, don't care about your `~/.vimrc` or anything you might pull from it that looks even remotely like vimscript.

I don't think it's possible/sensible to create complex mappings but you can, at least, do some remapping in your `~/.inputrc`. Here are a few pointers:

- `$ man readline` has a list of the vi keybindings available in `vi-mode`. Just do this search to jump to the listing: `/vi mode bindings`. As a side note, `man` accepts a lot of `vi`-like commands like `/?nNgG<C-f><C-b>`. I learned it like 3 weeks ago and it changed my (CLI) life.
- The list of commands available in `readline` can be found with `/editing commands`.
- [This old post on linuxforums](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/applications/141718-solved-howto-remap-bash-keys-vi-mode.html) explains succintly how to remap some keys in `vi`-mode. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your bash to be always in vi mode, put `set -o vi` in your `.bashrc`. It does not make sense to put it in your `.vimrc` as bash doen't care about it, like @three already said